# SplashScreen not working on Android Cordova 4.0.2

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I installed cordova-plugin-splashscreen but this doesnt help me.
What lines should I add to my config.xml file and where to place the splash.9.png file?

Previously (before updating my Cordova version to the latest one) splashscreen was working fine with the following options:

```
  <preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />
  <preference name="splashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

and one splash.9.png file in res/drawable folded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: manually display splash using navigator.splashscreen.show() and hide()

Comment: Not a good idea because I can use this method only when deviceready is fired, not from the app start

Answer (score 0):

Add your splash screen in respective drawable folder to match for all density devices.
and dont mention the value screen.png in preference.mention as like .(make sure your value is the file name of your splash image)

[Reference Link](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/need-help-with-displaying-splash-screen-on-android-cordova-3-6/10436/3)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it!
The problem was in the external ad SDK - AppJolt. As soon as I turned it off it began working again!